# Training a basic TensorFlow Model using the GradientTape

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, gradienttape

Simply for education purposes, I was trying to build upon the [Basic training loops](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/basic_training_loops) tutorial from the TensorFlow homepage to create a simple neural network that classifies points in the plane.

So, I have some points in `[0,1]x[0,1]` stored in a tensor `x` of shape `(250, 2, 1)` and the corresponding labels `(1. or 0.)` stored in a tensor `y` of shape `(250,1,1)`. Then I do

```
import tensorflow as tf

w0 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([4,2]), name = 'w0')
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1,4]), name = 'w1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4,1]), name = 'b1')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]), name = 'b2')

loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

def forward(x):
  x0 = x
  z1 = tf.matmul(w0, x0) + b1
  x1 = tf.nn.relu(z1)
  z2 = tf.matmul(w1, x1) + b2
  x2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z2)
  return x2

with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    current_loss = loss(y, forward(x))

gradients = t.gradient(current_loss, [b1, b2, w0, w1])
```

What I get is a list of tensors of the expected shape but only containing zeros. Anyone some advice?

Comment: Better zero than `None`! What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens because the labels/predictions do not have the expected shapes. In particular, the loss function [tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) expects labels to be provided in a one-hot representation, but your labels and predictions have shape `(250, 1, 1)` and the behaviour of the loss function is unclear in this situation. Using [tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy)
 instead should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. One-Hot encoded my labels and everything works out beautifully!